# Why should I not use incremental builds for release binaries?

Tags: rust, compilation

I noticed that as my project grows, the release compilation/build time gets slower at a faster pace than I expected (and hoped for). I decided to look into what I could do to improve compilation speed. I am *not* talking about the initial build time, which involves compilation of dependencies and is largely irrelevant.

One thing that seems to be helping significantly is the `incremental = true` profile setting. On my project, it seems to shorten build time by ~40% on 4+ cores. With fewer cores the gains are even larger, as builds with `incremental = true` don't seem to use (much) parallelization. With the default (for `--release`) `incremental = false` build times are 3-4 times slower on a single core, compared to 4+ cores.

What are the reasons to refrain from using `incremental = true` for production builds? I don't see any (significant) increase in binary size or storage size of cached objects. I read somewhere it is possible that incremental builds lead to slightly worse performance of the built binary. Is that the only reason to consider or are there others, like stability, etc.?

I know this could vary, but is there any data available on how much of a performance impact might be expected on real-world applications?

Comment: My understanding matches what you have read – incremental builds have slightly less potential for optimization. The idea is that you use debug builds during the development cycle, so these builds should have fast compile times. The release build is intended to build, well, a release, so it should have fast run time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an incremental build for production releases, because it is:

- not reproducible (i.e. you can't get the exact same binary by compiling it again) and
- quite possibly subtly broken (incremental compilation is way more complex and way less tested than clean compilation, in particular with optimizations turned on).